# How can i sort by a property with "_" underscore in JPA/hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, jpa

JPA split my sort property by "_" default, so it throw No property found exception.
If i remove the underscore from variable, it works fine.

But i just wanna keep the "_" in my entity property, how can i do?

Variable:

```
@Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
private LocalDateTime create_Time;
```

Pageable:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, 10, Sort.Direction.DESC,"create_Time");
```

The exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property create found for type Rtm_App!

at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:546)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:500)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:653)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:608)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:407)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:377)
```

Where split the property

```
public class PropertyPath implements Iterable<PropertyPath> {

private static final String DELIMITERS = "_\\.";
private static final String ALL_UPPERCASE = "[A-Z0-9._$]+";
private static final Pattern SPLITTER = Pattern.compile("(?:[%s]?([%s]*?[^%s]+))".replaceAll("%s", DELIMITERS));

public static PropertyPath from(String source, TypeInformation<?> type) {
    List<String> iteratorSource = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher matcher = SPLITTER.matcher("_" + source);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        iteratorSource.add(matcher.group(1));
    }

    Iterator<String> parts = iteratorSource.iterator();

    PropertyPath result = null;
    Stack<PropertyPath> current = new Stack<PropertyPath>();

    while (parts.hasNext()) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = create(parts.next(), type, current);
            current.push(result);
        } else {
            current.push(create(parts.next(), current));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's not good practice to have `_` in variable names.

Comment: Are you sure about where your error is coming from?  JPA doesn't disallow snake case.  And if you are using snake case to match your db, why are you using the @Column annotation?

Comment: Sure, org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from method split property by "_". I used idea POJOs.groovy generate the entity, add @Column in the groovy script.

Comment: Spring data JPA is heavily based on conventions. Breaking them will lead to problems. Respect the standard Java naming conventions, and everything will work better.